# Compare live data in json api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm calling JSON data from an API, I want to compare previous data with the current one,
I'm calling this API through javascript and using interval to call it realtime
https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD,AED?_=1631085552208
now I want to compare the previous API call and the current API call data and check rather the chart is going up or down,
here's my current code:

```
function rates_update(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD,AED',
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        
        
        var gold_aed_ask = data['items'][0]['xauPrice']+0;
        var gold_usd_ask = data['items'][1]['xauPrice']+0;
        
        var silver_usd_ask = data['items'][1]['xagPrice']+0;
        var silver_aed_ask = data['items'][0]['xagPrice']+0;
       
        var gold_aed = data['items'][0]['xauPrice'];
        var gold_usd = data['items'][1]['xauPrice'];
        
        var silver_usd = data['items'][1]['xagPrice'];
        var silver_aed = data['items'][0]['xagPrice'];
    }
    });
}

setInterval(function(){ rates_update(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to make the compare

Answer (score 0):

use database e.g mongoDB and create chart from values fetched from database, and whenever the chart updates itself send values to database chart will update itself according to values in database

Comment: i don't want charts, i just want to display colors according to value comparison,

Comment: okay then store the value in a variable and when new value came, compare it with the previously stored value, then make a if statement to compare both of them 
`if (previousVal>CurrentVal){
//CurrentVal Go Green//
PreviousVal=CurrentVal
}
else{
//CurrentVal Go Red//
PreviousVal=CurrentVal
}
`
update PreviousVal with currentVal

Comment: `var goldold=0
function rates_update(){
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD,AED',
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        
        console.log("newPrice: ",data['items'][0]['xauPrice']+0)
        console.log("OldPrice: ",goldold)
        

        
        goldold = data['items'][0]['xauPrice']+0;
        console.log("-------------------------------")
        
    }
    });
}

setInterval(function(){ rates_update(); }, 1000);`

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.